# Apple Watch with Android ir Windows PC?

Tags: windows, android, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch but I don't have an IPhone or Mac.

I want to use my Windows 10 PC, or my android phone with the Apple Watch.

How do I do this?

(Maybe using an Iphone emulator on PC? There must be some way to use the apple watch with Android, or Windows)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmmm
It's seems to be impossible

https://www.quora.com/Will-the-Apple-Watch-work-with-Android-devices

Answer to your edit :

You can't have an iPhone emulator on PC (you need Xcode).

Comment: And what about windows 10?

Comment: The Apple Watch need a phone to work (internet connection, localisation...) you can't do that with a Computer. But it's logically possible to push some apps to the Apple Watch from iTunes on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use the Apple Watch without having an Apple iPhone (and an iPhone 5 or later for that matter). It can't even be set up without first being paired to an iPhone. Windows 10 won't work either (the Apple Watch isn't even compatible with OS X on the Mac). You'll just have to save the Apple Watch until you can upgrade to an iPhone---you can find a used iPhone 5 for less than $200 on eBay or a 5S or 6 or 6S for more.